# Passing Parameter from MDIParent to MDIChild Form

Tags: c#

In C# Windows application, I have a Login Form, MdiParent Form and several Mdichild forms. When a user logs in successfully the Mdi Parent form is launched and then the user can launch the Child forms by clicking buttons on the MDI Parent.In the MDI Parent form I have a method:

```
public void ShoworActivate<T>(string loggedUser)where T: Form
{
   var k = MdiChildren.Where(c==>c.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstorDefault();
   if(k= null)
    {
      k = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
      ......More code
    }
}
```

I need to pass the parameter string loggedUser to child forms but when I put the parameter in the constructor of the child form, I get an error :
{"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."}

How can I solve this?
I don't want to use Child Form = new ChildForm(string loggedUser).This works.

Comment: Where and how do you get that error? Give us more context so we can understand what's going on. The constructor injection seems the better option for this, but otherwise a public property or method is good as a second option.

Comment: I get the error at ....k = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateInstance(typeof(T),loggedUser);

Comment: This is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing over engineering by using reflection to create form instance. You could have used factory for creating forms.

Anyways for your current problem you need to use another version of `CreateInstance` method which also takes parameters to be passed in the constructor of the target type.

```
k = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, loggedUser);
```

You can refer various overrides of `CreateInstance` method at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you would have to use Factory for creating forms, how would you have done it?Thank you.